# Undefined method "_path" in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to create a new model and provide user a link to a form to fill the model object.

My model (/models/paypal_order):

```
class PaypalOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :card_number, :card_verification

end
```

My controller (controllers/paypal_order_controller.rb):

```
class PaypalOrderController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @paypal_order = PaypalOrder.new
    end

end
```

My view (views/paypal_order/new.html.erb):

```
<%form_for PaypalOrder.new do |f|%>  #also tried <%form_for @paypal_order do |f|%>
<%= f.error_messages %>
<p>
    <%= f.label :first_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.label :last_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.label :card_type %><br />
    <%= f.select :card_type, [["Visa","visa"],["MasterCard", "master"],["Discover","discover"],["American Express","american_express"]] %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.label :card_number %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :card_number %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.label :card_verification, "Card Verification Value (CVV)" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :card_verification %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.label :card_expires_on %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :card_expires_on, :discard_day =>true, :start_year => Date.today.year, :end_year => (Date.today.year+25), :add_month_numbers => true %>
</p>
<%end%>
```

The link:

```
  <div class="payment_options">
  <div class="available_payment_options">
  <div class="online_payment_option">
    <h3>PayPal</h3>
    <%= link_to "Checkout", new_paypal_order_path %>
  </div>
```

entry in routes.rb:

```
resources :paypal_order
```

But on clicking the link I'm getting the following error:

```
NoMethodError in Paypal_order#new

Showing /home/nish/repos/new/test/voylla_staging_changes/app/views/paypal_order/new.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `paypal_orders_path' for #<#<Class:0x101f7e98>:0x101e5b94>
Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <%form_for PaypalOrder.new do |f|%>
2:  <%= f.error_messages %>
3:  <p>
4:      <%= f.label :first_name %><br />
```

I am not able to understand why I am getting this error. Also why is the form looking for `paypal_order**s**_path`, shouldn't it be `paypal_order_path` instead

**EDIT** rake routes output:

```
                               paypal_order_index GET    /paypal_order(.:format)                                                   {:action=>"index", :controller=>"paypal_order"}
                                                  POST   /paypal_order(.:format)                                                   {:action=>"create", :controller=>"paypal_order"}
                                 new_paypal_order GET    /paypal_order/new(.:format)                                               {:action=>"new", :controller=>"paypal_order"}
                                edit_paypal_order GET    /paypal_order/:id/edit(.:format)                                          {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"paypal_order"}
                                     paypal_order GET    /paypal_order/:id(.:format)                                               {:action=>"show", :controller=>"paypal_order"}
                                                  PUT    /paypal_order/:id(.:format)                                               {:action=>"update", :controller=>"paypal_order"}
                                                  DELETE /paypal_order/:id(.:format)                                               {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"paypal_order"}
```

Comment: Can you post your rake routes output?

Comment: @Pavan How can I do that??

Comment: Go to the current path in your terminal and just do rake routes and enter.

Comment: Shouldn't the controller name be `PaypalOrdersController` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First change first line to:

```
<%= form_for @paypal_order do |f|%>
```

second change routes to :

```
resources :paypal_orders
```

Also change controller class to

```
class PaypalOrdersController < ApplicationController

..
end
```

And controller file name to paypal_orders_controller.rb

Comment: I'm getting a 404 now

Comment: changed the view to '/paypal_orders/new.html.erb'. It worked but the form does not appear

Comment: no issue..do refresh your page or once restart your server and make sure you changed checkout link to new_paypal_orders_path..also when u are getting 404 before or after submitting the form

Comment: ohk ..i got it use this <%= form_for @paypal_order do |f|%>

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the plural of the model name when creating a `resources` controller. If you rename your controller to `PaypalOrdersController` and change the routing to `resources :paypal_orders` it should work.

Comment: Getting a 404 after making the controller name and routes resource plural

Comment: changed the view to '/paypal_orders/new.html.erb'. It worked, but the form does not appear. A blank page shows up instead